# How to display questions and options(as a radiobuttonlist) in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, radiobuttonlist

I am developing an application (Quiz Engine) in Asp.Net with C#. I have a database table (Q_ID,Question,option1,option2,option3,answer).
What I want is, to retrieve these data   and display to the user as Question and Answer and enable the user to select with the Radio button.  My problem is that how I can display this Question and options in radiobuttonlist.
my asp page is

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Vertical">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <br />
                   <table class="auto-style1">
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
                               </asp:RadioButtonList>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:DataList>
```

and my cod behind is like

```
  public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
        private void BindData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=webuser2014";
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("select LO_id,Q_Id,level,Question,option1,option2 from quiz WHERE LO_id='LO111'", cn);
                adp.Fill(dt);

            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataList2.DataSource = dt;
                DataList2.DataBind();

            }
            foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList2.Items)
            {
                RadioButtonList RadioButtonList2 = (RadioButtonList)DataList2.FindControl("RadioButtonList2");
                //RadioButtonList2.Items.Clear();
                RadioButtonList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("option1".ToString(), "option1".ToString()));
                RadioButtonList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("option2".ToString(), "option2".ToString()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: how to retrieve option1,option2 from database and display it in radiobutonlist for each question.